# Haskell - exit a program with a specified error code

Tags: haskell, error-code

In Haskell, is there a way to exit a program with a specified error code? The resources I've been reading typically point to the `error` function for exiting a program with an error, but it seems to always terminate the program with an error code of `1`.

```
[martin@localhost Haskell]$ cat error.hs
main = do
    error "My English language error message"
[martin@localhost Haskell]$ ghc error.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( error.hs, error.o )
Linking error ...
[martin@localhost Haskell]$ ./error 
error: My English language error message
[martin@localhost Haskell]$ echo $?
1
```

Comment: Probably you then should use [`System.Exit`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/System-Exit.html).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I think that's what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [`exitWith`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/System-Exit.html#v:exitWith) from [`System.Exit`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/System-Exit.html):

```
main = exitWith (ExitFailure 2)
```

I would add some helpers for convenience:

```
exitWithErrorMessage :: String -> ExitCode -> IO a
exitWithErrorMessage str e = hPutStrLn stderr str >> exitWith e

exitResourceMissing :: IO a
exitResourceMissing = exitWithErrorMessage "Resource missing" (ExitFailure 2)
```

Answer (score 5):

An alternative that allows an error message only is `die`

```
import System.Exit

tests = ... -- some value from the program
testsResult = ... -- Bool value overall status

main :: IO ()
main = do
    if testsResult then
        print "Tests passed"
    else
        die (show tests)
```

The accepted answer allows setting the exit error code though, so it's closer to the exact phrasing of the question.